# How to write an expression to display 2 fields in a string in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-expression

I am trying to take two fields and display them in a string in my SSReport. How would I properly write the expression for this type of scenario.

> Fields!Title1.Value
>   Fields!Title2.Value

Expression:

> = Fields!Title1.Value is stored in the Fields!Title2.Value room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in a textbox:

```
=CStr(Fields!Title1.Value) & CStr(Fields!Title2.Value)
```